# React js - pass value to child to parent to another child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the data from Child > parent > child

Child

```
  {this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
                    <li className='card' key={index}>
                        <span>{item.continent} </span>
                        <ul className="accordion-body">
                            {item.regions.map((c, i) => (
                                <li key={i} onClick={this.props.toggleContent}>
                                    <img src={c.flag}/> {c.country}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                ))}
```

Basically I need to get selected country and some other values from the child and pass to parent
and pass those values to another child.

My Parent

```
<div className="modal-header">
                <h2>Choose your {title}</h2>
                <a href="#" className="model-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i
                    className="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-body">
                {showCountry && <CountryList toggleContent={this.toggleContent}/>}

                {showLanguages && <RegionList country={country} flag={flag} languages={languages}
                                              toggleContent={this.toggleContentRegion.bind(this)}/>}

            </div>
```

and

```
    toggleContent = () => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            showCountry: !this.state.showCountry,
            showLanguages: !this.state.showLanguages,
            title: 'language',
            country: 'country',
            languages: [],
            flag: 'flag'
        });
    }
```

I tried to use below

```
 <li key={i} onClick={this.props.toggleContent(c.country)}>
                                    <img src={c.flag}/> {c.country}
                                </li>
```

and access it from parent

```
  toggleContent = (country) => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            showCountry: !this.state.showCountry,
            showLanguages: !this.state.showLanguages,
            title: 'language',
            country: country,
            languages: [],
            flag: 'flag'
        });
    }
```

But, my components not working correctly When do that and always shows the 2 child component.

Are there any proper way to pass the data to parent from a json array?

Comment: So I just want to clarify.It seems as though you want a modal window to pop up every time the user clicks an item on the list and for that modal to contain details about the  country clicked

Comment: Model will popup with the country list,
and when they click the country, they will see the language list.
It's a country switcher,
User will see the current country in main nav,
when they click it they will get a model popup with all the countries,
when they select a country from the list, they will get the langugage list.( change country component to langugage component)

Answer (score 0):

So the best way I would handle this would be to make the import your parent class components into the child , place it at the very top of the child JSX but hide it by default. The modal would be fixed, background covering the full page  and at a z-index higher than the rest of the child components, so that way only the modal contents are the only accessible things . You would have a state that "toggles on" the modal for each click of the item list and a close button that toggles it off. You would update the modal content and toggle it on for every click

In terms of the second child, you can just show it on the same modal

Comment: All the switching is working fine. The only issue I have is pass the data child to parent to 2nd child.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this :)

```
 render() {
        var toggleContent  =   this.props.toggleContent;
        return (
            <div className="modal-wrapper">

                <ul className="country-list">
                    {this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
                        <li className='card' key={index}>
                            <span>{item.continent} </span>
                            <ul className="accordion-body">
                                {item.regions.map((c, i) => (
                                    **<li key={i} onClick={() => toggleContent(c.country,c.flag, c.languages, c.region)} >**
                                        <img src={c.flag}/> {c.country}
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Changed below line

**onClick={() => toggleContent(c.country,c.flag, c.languages, c.region)**